# subprocess.Popen doesn't react the same way in PyCharm as in Windows CMD when there is "funny" character like �

Tags: python, unicode, cmd, pycharm, subprocess

First of all, Yes I've already search and didn't find out any solution. So, the problem is :

I have a first python script `CommandLine.py` created in PyCharm who request a Json file from a website and I print the result on Terminal.

```
    for val in my_json[:200]:
        i += 1
        print("    {} - {}".format(str(i).zfill(2), val))
```

This command line script is use like this :

`python CommandLine.py --user MyUserName --password MyPWD --website www.about.com --output C:\Users\MyName\MyFolder --mail YesOrNo and so on...`

Everything works fine, I get the result, even with russian characters, japanese characters and also "funny" characters in the result (like this one : �). It works in PyCharm and in Windows CMD same way ("funny" characters like this � are printed in both).

But this first script is a lil bit annoying with all arguments (for me, for budies...), so I created a second python script named `GUI.py`. It is a Graphic User Interface with the `Tkinter` python lib. You can use all the Entry widget on it to choose the arguments needed. Then you click on the Button widget and you get the result in a Text widget named "Console" (to "emulate" terminal). I do that with `subprocess.Popen` like this :

```
    cmd = 'python CommandLine.py --user MyUserName --password MyPWD 
            --website www.about.com --output C:\Users\MyName\MyFolder 
            --mail YesOrNo and so on...'

    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')

    while True:
        returnStatus = process.poll()
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        if returnStatus is not None:
            break
        if output:
            line = output.strip() # leave the white space
            console.insert('end', line + '\n')
            console.yview_moveto(1)
            console.update()
```

`GUI.py` works fine in PyCharm, I get the same result as do `CommandLine.py` (with the non latin character) without code error.

BUT ! Yes, But. In Windows CMD, this second script `GUI.py` always crashed with this code error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MyName\MyFolder\CommandLine.py", line 343, in <module>
    print("    {} - {}".format(str(i).zfill(2), val))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 10-11: character maps to <undefined>
```

I do not understand why because the first script `CommandLine.py` works fine alone in both PyCharm and Win CMD.

Is `subprocess.Popen` the problem in CMD ? I think so, but can't find out a solution.

I've tried :

- changing encoding with `mbcs`, `ansi`, `ISO-8859-1` in `process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')`
- remove encoding in `process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')`
- add `Shell=True`
- do `chcp 65001` in CMD before `python GUI.py`

Nothing resolve the problem, still have code error.

Btw, I use `subprocess.Popen` to get "live" output to print it my "console" widget.

Where am I wrong ? Need help please.
Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry, english is not my native language.

Comment: `encodings\cp1252` indeed will be going to be a problem with all other characters than in the very limited Windows Latin-1 encoding, and usually your `chcp 65001` would fix this. But the fact remains that your funny `�` will still map to an Undefined Character -- and this cannot be displayed, by design. Do you have a Unicode value for that character? If it's always the same one, filter it out before attempting to print.

Comment: The thing is that the first script works well alone in both PyCharm and CMD. So why it isn't working in the second script. That will be maybe my future workaround to modify the first script to escape these characters. But if it works (the first script) why change it ? Just for moment wanna change the second script...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to call subproces.Popen with `env={'PYTHONIOENCODING': 'utf-8'}`?

According to your error, Python has selected a "system encoding" (to use for IO streams) of cp1252, which aside from being incompatible with the encoding you're telling subprocess to expect *can not represent all possible characters you get from your inputs*.

`PYTHONIOENCODING` *should* override the process Python uses to select a system encoding, and just encode the output stream as utf-8, which should be able to represent any input, and matches the expectations of your wrapper.

Comment: Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python

Comment: You need to pass in all your environment variables in addition to `PYTHONIOENCODING`. Try `env=os.environ | {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}`